# How to apply formula to only certain rows of pivot table in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, pivot, pivot-table, percentage

Original df I have:

```
    year security_software  usage
0   2006        anti_virus     77
1   2006          firewall     64
2   2006  security_updates     59
3   2007        anti_virus     84
4   2007          firewall     71
5   2007  security_updates     52
6   2008        anti_virus     91
7   2008          firewall     81
8   2008  security_updates     63
9   2009        anti_virus     90
10  2009          firewall     83
11  2009  security_updates     61
12  2010        anti_virus     90
13  2010          firewall     85
14  2010  security_updates     67
15  2011        anti_virus     89
16  2011          firewall     84
17  2011  security_updates     61
18  2012        anti_virus     83
19  2012          firewall     72
20  2012  security_updates     52
21  2013        anti_virus     84
22  2013          firewall     71
23  2013  security_updates     75
24  2014        anti_virus     81
25  2014          firewall     69
26  2014  security_updates     79
27  2015        anti_virus     80
28  2015          firewall     61
29  2015  security_updates     79
```

I have created a pivot table for my data, and added a "Total" row for it, with below commands.

```
sec_pivot = df.pivot(index="security_software",columns='year',values = "usage")
sec_pivot.loc['Total'] = sec_pivot.sum()
print(sec_pivot)

year security_software  2006  2007  2008  2009  2010  2011  2012  2013  2014  2015
0           anti_virus    77    84    91    90    90    89    83    84    81    80
1             firewall    64    71    81    83    85    84    72    71    69    61
2     security_updates    59    52    63    61    67    61    52    75    79    79
```

How do I change all the usage aggregates into percentage of the total value, without affecting the "Total" row itself?

Comment: Is that the original `df`? There is no column `year` nor `usage`

Comment: My apologies. It's correct now, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `loc` with index slicing

```
sec_pivot.loc["anti_virus":"security_updates"]/sec_pivot.loc["Total"] * 100

year                2006    2007        2008    
security_software           
anti_virus          38.5    40.579710   38.723404
firewall            32.0    34.299517   34.468085
security_updates    29.5    25.120773   26.808511
```

If you want to replace values in original df, just assign back

```
sec_pivot.loc["anti_virus":"security_updates"] = sec_pivot.loc["anti_virus":"security_updates"]/sec_pivot.loc["Total"] * 100



year                2006    2007        2008    
security_software           
anti_virus          38.5    40.579710   38.723404
firewall            32.0    34.299517   34.468085
security_updates    29.5    25.120773   26.808511
Total              200.0    207.000000  235.000000
```

If not in index, gets little more complicated, but not much:

```
sec_pivot.loc[sec_pivot.index != 'Total', 1:] = sec_pivot[sec_pivot.index != 'Total'].iloc[:,1:]/sec_pivot.iloc[:,1:].loc["Total"] * 100
```

Notice that `1:` means *from column 1 until the end*. Im considering your years start at column index 1 (with year 2006). If you have other columns in your `df`, change `1:` to `a:b` where `a` in the index of your first year column, and `b` is the index of you last year column

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How can we change it if there is reset_index() for the pivot table?

`sec_pivot = df.pivot(index="security_software",columns='year',values = "usage").reset_index()`

Comment: I have tried the code with reset_index() but the string column becomes NaN.

`security_software
NaN
NaN
NaN
NaN
anti_virusfirewallsecurity_updates`

Comment: @Venice Did you assign in the left-hand side as `sec_pivot.loc[sec_pivot.index != 'Total', 1:]` = ?

Comment: Ah! I missed out the `1:`. Thanks so much for your help!